# Please help with this serial communication program

Tags: c#, serial-port

What is wrong with this? I am trying to communicate to a TReX motor controller.  I need to send the following data "DA 1F 1F" or "0xDA 0x1F 0x1F"

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public class PortChat
{
    static SerialPort _serialPort;
    public static void Main()
    {

        StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();
        _serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
        _serialPort.Open();
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;        
        _serialPort.Write("Byte[DA 1F 1F]");
        _serialPort.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  What does it do?  What doesn't it do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create Com port instance with needed parameters.
2. Open Com port
3. Write command to it
4. Close it

   ```
       static SerialPort _serialPort;
       public static void Main()
       {
           _serialPort = new SerialPort();
           _serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
           _serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
           _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
           _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
           _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;


       _serialPort.Open();


       byte[] command = new byte[] { 0xDA, 0x1F, 0x1F };
       _serialPort.Write(command, 0, command.Length);


       _serialPort.Close();
   }
   ```

Comment: How do you put running time for the motors to turn for a specific time length??

Comment: @Christian, you must see the device protocol. I think it has start and stop commands. Send "start" command, wait a specific time, than send "stop" command.